# Audio/video streaming to mobile browsers

Tags: browser, mobile, streaming, wap

I am developing a WAP/mobile website that would allow users to stream audio/video (although the priority is audio) via their mobile browsers..

For music I would be streaming mp3 files, and for video I would be streaming flv and 3gp files (but mostly 3gp).

Can anyone recommend solutions (i.e. what to use and/or a point to the right direction) to enable streaming audio/video to a mobile browser?

AFAIK, there is RTSP (probably via Darwin Streaming Server?) which is supported in most 3G devices, and flash lite. (Would using flash lite as a player even be a good idea, since the users would need to have flash lite installed on their mobile devices? I'm not that familiar with flash.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most mobile phones support video streaming via RTSP, and the cheapest method is the Darwin Stream Server, and it integrates with the Real Video player

As for flash lite that has limited handset support so I wouldn't recommend using it.

The only thing I would add is that without wireless carrier support streaming of data to a mobile phone can be very expensive for an end user, so please ensure that the end user knows about the potential data charges

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know if Darwin Stream Server allows the streaming of remote files? e.g. serverA.com is running DSS, but it needs to stream 3gp files from serverB.com, which is not running DSS. I'm authorized by serverB to use their files but I don't have access to the server...